# Route/create a sub-domain in CakePHP, how to

Tags: php, cakephp, subdomain

I've tried solutions as such, but they don't see to address the problem Im at.

[How to create a sub-domain in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080996/how-to-create-a-sub-domain-in-cakephp/27085668#27085668)

I have a CakePHP app in publichtml/lastroarte.com running ok. I went to my DNS and created for a subdomain entries for sandbox.lastroarte.com a test subdomain for the new version of my which we'll be upload the new app.

If I browse to the subdomain now, it redirects me the home page of my domain, still displaying the url sandbox.lastroarte. I've found entries for the pages in the Routes file of Cake, although I have not found way to say a subdomain should display the index of its own folder (public_html/sandbox.lastroarte.com). Am I doing the right approach? How to achieve this?

Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you are running apache as your web server)

You have created a sub-domain, but have you created sites-available and sites-enabled files and restarted apache?

If you are using your host's control panel it will do this for you, but you will need to associate your public_html/sandbox.lastroarte.com directory to the sandbox.lastroarte.com sub-domain.

In short this doesn't sound like a Cake routing problem, it sounds like apache is routing traffic from sandbox.lastroarte.com to lastroarte.com.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. I'm sorry for not providing the info. I'm actually  using nginx. So I should search for subdomain creation in nginx's documentation. Righton, thanks Simon!